# Rails validates_uniqueness_of error message not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, internationalization, overriding, rails-activerecord

Respected ppl ...

I have many models, one example is as below  :

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :state_name
  belongs_to :location
  validates_uniqueness_of(:state_name)
  validates_presence_of(:state_name)
end
```

i want to add error message globally for the uniqueness of attributes ...

```
en:
   hello: "Hello world"
   errors:
     messages:
          taken: "अद्वितीय होना चाहिए/Data Already Exists"  
          blank: "रिक्त नहीं किया जा सकता है/can't be blank"
```

The one for blank is working perfectly but the taken is still not working & i still get the default "has already been taken" error message ...

Kindly help ...

Sincere Regards
-Sky

Comment: I suggest restarting your server - that code looks OK and sometimes I get strangeness with translations that only gets resolved by restarting the server, even in dev mode.

Comment: got it solved ...

I replaced my en.yml file with the one provided here : https://raw.github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/master/rails/locale/en.yml

and replaced the blank and taken from this file as suited by me ...

Everything is working now :D ....

Regards -Sky

Comment: Thnx sevenseacat :D ... even that works too !!!! .... holyness :D ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it solved ... I replaced my en.yml file with the one provided here : raw.github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/master/rails/locale/en.yml and replaced the "blank" and "taken" from this file as suited by me ... Everything is working now :D ....

Regards -Sky